# How to substitute NULL with empty string in sql 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Column `occurrence_limit` is money datatype,

If it is `NULL` I want just empty string (`''`), but it gives me `0.00`.

```
ISNULL(occurrence_limit,'')  as occurrence_limit
```

How can I simply have `''` instead of `0.00`?

Comment: The empty string is not a valid value for `money`. Why not just use `null`?

Comment: Don't. Simple as that. Handle it in your presentation layer. `''` is not a number, so it can't be stored as a `money` value, and it's implicitly converted to `0`. You most certainly don't want to treat your numbers as a `varchar` (as I can assure you that `100` is greater than `2`, not less than it) so leave it as it is.

Comment: The outcome goes to excel sheet. User requirements is to have blank if NULL

Comment: So fix what ever is outputting to Excel, @Serdia . *Most* applications don't actually display `NULL` they show an empty "cell", so what ever ETL process you are using is actually putting "NULL". Fix the ETL process. It's only really IDEs that tend to display `NULL`, as it *is* different to `''` when dealing with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, don't do it.  But if you need to:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), occurrence_limit), '') AS occurrence_limit
```

Comment: Just to give reason why it's bad: it's that the values aren't numerical anymore. For important things, like money, that is a problem. `'100'` is **less than** `'2'`, for example, and `'17' + '2'` is `'172'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP table #testStak create table #testStak(nombre varchar(50),moneycant money)

INSERT INTO #testStak VALUES ('ALFA',10) 
INSERT INTO #testStak VALUES ('BETA',NULL) 
INSERT INTO #testStak VALUES ('GAMMA',5000)

SELECT nombre,ISNULL(CAST(moneycant AS varchar),'') FROM #testStak
```

Comment: Not related to question

Comment: actually it does, its a form to put an empty space instead of 0.00 in a column of money.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(occurrence_limit, 0),'')  as occurrence_limit
```